# problemas con un sistema de notificaciones en angular

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

estoy tratando de hacer un sistema de notificaciones en mi aplicacion hago una peticion ajax a mi api resfull que me devuelve  las notificaciones que estan activas estas las guardo en el localstorage y desde el localstorage las muestro en mi navbar   el problema es que me sale el siguiente problema con angular

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el error aparece cuando le doy a iniciar sesion y voy a mi pagina de administrador que es la pagina de inicio el error desaparece cuando actualizo la pantalla adjunto mi servicio y mi componente

este es mi servicio que consume a la api

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { UserService } from './userController';
import { global } from "./global";
import { Notification } from 'src/app/interfaces/notification';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotificationService {
  public url:string;
  public token:string;
  constructor(
    private _userService:UserService,
    private _http:HttpClient,
  ) { 
    this.url = global.url;
    this.token = this._userService.getToken();
  }
  //setea el status de la notificacion en el backend
  set(data:any):Observable<any>{
    let params = JSON.stringify(data);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' )
                                   .set( 'Authorization', this.token );
    return this._http.post(this.url + 'notification/set-status ', params, {headers:headers});
  }
  //obtiene todas as notificaciones activas al momento
  getAll():Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' )
                                   .set( 'Authorization', this.token );

    return this._http.get<Notification[]>(this.url + 'notification/actives', {headers:headers}).pipe(tap(
      res =>{
        if(res){
          this.saveOnStorage(res);
        }
      },
      err =>{
        console.log(err);
      }
    ));
  }

  saveOnStorage(notifications:any){
    return localStorage.setItem('notifys',JSON.stringify(notifications));
  }
  getFromStorage(){
    let notifications = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notifys')!);
    return notifications;
  }
}
```

y este es mi componente navbar

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy,DoCheck, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
//models
import { Notification } from 'src/app/models/notification';
//services
import  { NotificationService } from 'src/app/services/notification.service'
//material
import { MatIcon } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatBadge } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatButton } from '@angular/material/button';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/services/userController';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck,OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  subscriptions:Subscription []=[];
  public notifications:Notification[] = [];
  public _notifications!:number
  public user:any;
  constructor(
    private _userService:UserService,
    private _notificationService:NotificationService,
  ) {
    this.user = _userService.getIdentity();
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getNotifi();
  }
  ngAfterViewInit():void{
    this.notifications = this._notificationService.getFromStorage().notifications;
    this._notifications = this.notifications.length;
  }
  ngOnDestroy():void{
    this.subscriptions.forEach(sub => { sub.unsubscribe() } );
  }
  ngDoCheck(){
    this.notifications = this._notificationService.getFromStorage().notifications;
    this._notifications = this.notifications.length;
  }
  logOut(){
    this._userService.closeSession();
  }
  getNotifi(): void{
    this.subscriptions.push(
      this._notificationService.getAll().subscribe()
    );
  }
```

no se si estoy usando el hook incorrecto lo que pasa es que quiero que las notificaciones se vayan  mostrando siempre que modifique el localstorage por eso uso docheck
este es mi html del componente

```html
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light my-3">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/admin']">Navbar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <!--nav links -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-sm-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <!--item-->
            <div class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 text-center">
                <div class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      Clientes
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/admin/customers/register']">Registrar</a></li>
                      <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/admin/customers/list']">Lista</a></li>
                      <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/admin/customers/active']">Activos</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--item-->
                <div class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Inventario
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/admin/products/add']">Agregar Producto</a></li>
                  <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/admin/products/list']">Lista de Productos</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                <!--item-->
                <div class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Facturas
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/admin/payments/add/']">Generar</a></li>
                  <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/admin/payments/list']">Movimientos</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                <!--item-->
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-nav navbar-end text-center">

              <div class="nav-item d-flex dropdown">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center me-5 dropdown" *ngIf="notifications && notifications.length !=  0">
                  <!--mat button and badge-->
                  <button mat-icon-button data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside">
                    <mat-icon [matBadge]="_notifications" [matBadgeHidden]="_notifications == 0" matBadgeSize="small" class="notifications-bell">
                      notifications
                    </mat-icon>
                  </button>
                  <!--dropdawn menu-->
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="notificationDropdown">
                    <li><h3 class="dropdown-header text-center">Notificaciones</h3></li>
                    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                    <li *ngFor="let notification of notifications" class="p-2">
                      <a class="dropdown-item d-flex w-100" [routerLink]="['/admin/products/details/',notification.item.id]">
                        <mat-icon class="me-3">email</mat-icon> 
                        <div class="text-start">
                          <p>
                            Stock minimo alcanzado.
                          </p>
                          <p>
                            Quedan {{notification.item.product_quantity}} unidad/es de 
                            <span class="product-name">{{notification.item.name}}</span>.
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li *ngIf="notifications != null && notifications.length < 1">
                      <p class="dropdown-header text-center text-muted p-3">
                        No hay notificaciones 
                      </p>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-file-earmark-person" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M11 8a3 3 0 1 1-6 0 3 3 0 0 1 6 0z"/>
                    <path d="M14 14V4.5L9.5 0H4a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h8a2 2 0 0 0 2-2zM9.5 3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 11 4.5h2v9.255S12 12 8 12s-5 1.755-5 1.755V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h5.5v2z"/>
                  </svg>
                  {{user.name +' '+user.surname}}
                </a>
              
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" (click)='logOut()'>Cerrar sesion</a></li>
                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configuracion</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente se deba a que cuando estás intentando recuperar las notificaciones del servicio al inicio del localStorage, estas todavía no han sido cargadas y el método `getFromStorage` devuelve `null`.

Puedes solucionarlo fácilmente devolviendo un array vacío `[]` desde dicho método cuando `notifications` sea `null`.

saludos

Comment: que me recomiendas para optimizarlo de mejor manera ?